# Undesirable Link on Homepage on Blogger

Tags: blogger

I have a link on my homepage which did not exist before. How can I delete or hide this link?

Blog: http://www.ahmetvarlik.com/

The url the link goes: http://www.ahmetvarlik.com/search?updated-max=2000-02-01T23:29:00-08:00&max-results=24

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F27Os.jpg)

Note1: I used this code to hide "label" links like this on my "product designs" and "models and objects" pages:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isSearch'>
<style>
    .blog-pager { display: none; }
</style>
```

Note2: This code is hiding all older-newer links, but I do not know how to apply this code just for homepage:(

```
#blog-pager {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'>
  <style>
    #blog-pager { display: none; }
  </style>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I found a long solution. First, I applied `#blog-pager {visibility: hidden;}` to template. Then I applied `<style> .blog-pager {visibility: visible!important;} </style>` to each post I want to see "older-newer" links.